# What does the Gini index mean in a biochemical context?

Tags: biochemistry, biostatistics

What is the meaning of the Gini index, as specificed in this link, which describes the [Gini index of beta-glucopyranose bound to hexokinase](http://marid.bioc.cam.ac.uk/credo/ligands/1BDG/0/A/GLC%60501)?

Is this true that if Gini index has a very low value that means it doesn't interact much? If Gini index is high for a compound, it will interact?

Comment: they had a heature called gini index, wanted to know what that was

Comment: +1, thanks for the clarification. Edited answer to make more sense to me, feel free to roll back if that was wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The paper by [Graczyk (2007)](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17948979) is probably relevant for you. It says that the Gini index is a measure of reactive selectivity of kinases, with values close to zero indicating no selectivity and values close to one indicating high selectivity, and it is created in direct parallel to the Gini index in economics, which is used to describe economic inequality. In its basic form, the Gini coefficient is a [measure of statistical disperson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gini_coefficient). Also see [Anastassiadis et al. (2011)](http://www.nature.com/nbt/journal/v29/n11/full/nbt.2017.html?WT.ec_id=NBT-201111) for a more recent example where the index is used.

> **Abstract**
>   A novel application of the Gini coefficient for expressing selectivity of kinase inhibitors against a panel of kinases is proposed. This has been illustrated using single-point inhibition data for 40 commercially available kinase inhibitors screened against 85 kinases. Nonselective inhibitors are characterized by Gini values close to zero (Staurosporine, Gini 0.150). Highly selective compounds exhibit Gini values close to 1 (PD184352 Gini 0.905). The relative selectivity of inhibitors does not depend on the ATP concentration.

**References:**

[Graczyk. 2007. Gini coefficient: a new way to express selectivity of kinase inhibitors against a family of kinases. *J Med Chem.* 50(23)](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17948979)

[Anastassiadis et al. 2011. Comprehensive assay of kinase catalytic activity reveals features of kinase inhibitor selectivity. Nature Biotechnology 29: 1039–1045](http://www.nature.com/nbt/journal/v29/n11/full/nbt.2017.html?WT.ec_id=NBT-201111)

Comment: "expressing selectivity of kinase inhibitors against a panel of kinases is proposed" what does this line mean, please explain

Comment: @user3237995 I assume that it means that the gini index is calculated in relation to a specific set of kinases. Biochemistry is not my area though, but I'm interested in the Gini index in general. If you look at the paper they show e.g. that the Gini indices calculated from a set of 20 kinases are very similar to the indices calculated using an expanded set of 85 kinases.